# TSQL "select" or temp tables/cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project with financial data.
I have a table that contains closePrice column.
I need to select the data in a way where the closePrice for the previous time period becomes the open price for the next time period.

Data:

```
ClosePrice
0.77512
1.18488
0.87144
132.297
1.23644
151.804
```

Desired Result:

```
OpenPrice  ClosePrice
1.18488    0.77512
0.87144    1.18488
132.297    0.87144
1.23644    132.297
151.804    1.23644
           151.804
```

My question is... is there a way to accomplish this with a select statement without resorting to temp tables and/or cursor processing ?

Comment: You need a column to order by with. Doing a `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY` won't guarantee that the result set comes always in the same order, making the result non-deterministic. Once you know which column determines the order, then you can do a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourOrderingColumn)` to get a row number you can use to link previous row with next one.

Comment: How do we determine the order of these values? If this table you have is simply these values, then you won't be able to achicve this even with a cursor. I **assume** you have a date column of some kind?

Answer (score 6):

You want `lead()` function available fron SQL Server+12

```
select LEAD(ClosePrice) over(order by ?) as OpenPrice, ClosePrice
from table t
```

You could also use `apply` operator

```
select OpenPrice, ClosePrice 
from table t outer apply (
    select top 1 ClosePrice as OpenPrice
    from table where ? = t.?+1) tt
```

However, you would required to specify the name of column `?` (i.e. `id` or `row_no`) that could specify your column ordering

Comment: Note that Lead function requires at least SQL Server 2012 (OP didn't specify tho).

Comment: that did it.  Thank you very much.